# switch between landscape mode and portrait mode in Android Tablet(Samsung 10.1)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-manifest

I am creating app for android tab. i want to run in both Landscape and portrait mode.
I have use two folder Layout and Layout-land and in manifest file i have set configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation". if i remove orientation from configChanges than it works fine but it load activity again else layout setting is not working.

any suggestion?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Post your code that use both layout, the XML Layout, and Manifest XML, if necessary, here.

Comment: Normal behaviour is to destroy and recreate an Activity when it rotates, so that the entire view structure is recreated using the new (correct orientation) resource files. Setting configChanges="orientation" overrides this behaviour and tells the system you want to handle the rotation yourself.

Comment: just go through onRetain configuration in developer site..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

post your code or go through onRetain configuration method.